# nginx: server_names_hash_bucket_size error in logs and CPU reaches 100%

Tags: nginx

When we reload nginx, we see below message in logs,

```
nginx: [warn] could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either 
server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring 
server_names_hash_bucket_size
```

And we notice cpu goes upto 100% utlization during the reload. Does server_names_hash_bucket_size and cpu have anything to do with each other in this case? increasing bucket size will help in cpu ? as of now our server hangs for 1 0r 2 mins when we reload.

worker process settings are as below

```
worker_processes number  auto;  
worker_connections 2048;
```

Could anyone help us to fix this problem.

Comment: Nginx tells you quite explicitly that it can't create a good server names hash table, because one or both of the above parameters are set too low. How this affects the CPU, I don't know, but it obviously does. Anecdotal evidence: https://gist.github.com/muhammadghazali/6c2b8c80d5528e3118613746e0041263. See also http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html.

Comment: Are you able to improve startup time using those parameters?

Comment: added those max_size and bucket size in http in nginx.conf and restarted. still same issue with cpu. only difference is those errors disappeared from logs.